# laravel 7 route/url param in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I tried to pass parameter type=Business via GET request to
RegisterForm.

- In Welcome.blade
- I have two links to RegisterForm.

  ```
       @if (Route::has('register'))
       <a href="register?type=Business">Register Business</a>
       <a href="register?type=Applicant">Register Applicant</a>
       @endif
  ```
- In RegisterForm, I have hidden field like this:

  ```
     @if (isset($type))
     <input id="userType" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="userType" value="{{ $type }}">
      @endif
  ```
- Even Tried this way:

  ```
      @if (isset($type == 'Business'))
       <input id="userType" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="userType" value="{{ $type }}">
      @endif
  ```
- In Laravel side: Main page gets userTypes via:

  ```
    public function index()
    {

   $userTypes = array(
   'Applicant',
   'Business'       
   );
   return view('website::welcome', compact('userTypes'));
  }
  ```
- return view('website::welcome'
- means I have own package called "website".

Q) What do I missing, what is wrong my code ?

I am getting error from registerForm:

ParseError
syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' (View: register.blade.php)

Comment: where you defined `$type`?

Comment: you defined `$userTypes` not `$type`, so `$type` is undefined, also your  `$userTypes` is an array

Comment: type is coming from url, via GET parameter. type = Business.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359582/laravel-route-with-parameters three years old answer, was success and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is comming from this below line.

```
 @if (isset($type == 'Business'))
```

You need to call two conditions as below. for `isset` and `comparison`

```
@if (isset($type) && $type== 'Business')
```