# Laravel route pass multiple parameters, API

Tags: laravel, api

I want to call several parameters to the link: country id, table id, and value from table "name."

```
class InsuranceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => '',
            'arabic' => '',
            'country_id' => '',
        ]);

        $insurances = Insurance::filter($request->all())
            ->paginate(config('custom.items_per_page'));

        return response()->json($insurances);
    }

    public function getInsurances($country_id)
    {
        $insurances = Insurance::where('country_id', $country_id)
            ->paginate(config('custom.items_per_page'));
        
        return response()->json($insurances);
    }
}
```

**API Route**

```
Route::get('insurance&country={$countryid}&id={id}&title={name}', 
    'Api\InsuranceController@getInsurancesFilter')
        ->name('getInsurancesFilter');
```

Comment: This `insurance&country={$countryid}&id={id}&title={name}` is a weird string to put in a route. Do you intend to use the parameters as query parameters ? `yousite/insurance&country/?id=1&title=somestring` or as function arguments ?

Comment: function arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel route with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359582/laravel-route-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Route::get('insurance&country/{countryid?}/{id?}/{name?}', 'Api\InsuranceController@getInsurancesFilter')->name('getInsurancesFilter');

    public function getInsurances($countryId=null,$id=null,$name=null)
    {
        $insurances = Insurance::where('country_id', $countryId)
            ->paginate(config('custom.items_per_page'));

        return response()->json($insurances);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change API route to below

```
  Route::get('insurance/{county_id}/{id}/{name}', 'Api\InsuranceController@getInsurancesFilter')->name('getInsurancesFilter');
```

In InsuranceController

```
public function getInsurances($country_id,$id,$name)
    {   
    $insurances = Insurance::where('country_id', $country_id)->paginate(config('custom.items_per_page'));
            return response()->json($insurances);
 }
```